# Pandas series.map changes values to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working on an SMS dataset that has two columns a "label column" which is consists of "ham/spam" and another column with "messages" consist of a bunch of strings.

I converted the "Label column" to numeric labels, ham=1, and spam=0

```
#Converting our labels to numeric labels
# ham = 0 and spam = 1
dfcat = dataset['label']=dataset.label.map({'ham':1,'spam':0})
dfcat.head()
```

so when I run the above code the first time it gave me the exact thing am looking for but after I ran it again it started giving me "Nan".

```
Out[108]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Please, I need a way to fix this.

Comment: [series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) has this to say in the docs:" Values that are not found in the dict are converted to NaN, unless the dict has a default value". The second time you run the code it doesn't find either search string, so it maps 1 and 0 to `NaN`

Comment: okay, thank you, but how can i go about it, because physically looking at my dataset which is the "label column" there is no missing data (i might be wrong). i am just looking for a way to go about it, thank you.

Comment: The best way to go about it is to not run that line of code again, or to add `1:1, 0:0` to your mapping dictionary if you absolutely must run the code again

Comment: okay, if i get you right, i should change the "ham":1, "spam":0 in the mapping dict to 1:1, 0:0

Comment: I'm still not clear on why you're running the same line of code again. It would be better, IMO, to change the mapping dictionary to `{"ham":1, "spam":0,1:1,0:0}` so it works whether it's the first run or not

Comment: I've added the solution as an answer to the question in case you choose to accept it with the checkmark

Comment: To echo G.Anderson, it's really difficult to come up with a good reason why you would want to use the same mapping to map rows you already mapped... This *really* seems like the XY problem; you are asking for the solution to a problem that should not exist in the first place. It would be better to understand the decisions that led you to this odd situation and how you could better organize your analysis to prevent it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

@G. Anderson gave the reason why are you seeing those NaN the second time you rerun it.

As for a way to handle categorical variables in Python, one could use [one hot encoding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). Toy example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c"], "label": ["ham", "spam", "ham"]})
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix="ohe", drop_first=True, columns=["label"])
df_ohe
```

However, it also depends on the amount of categorical variables and their cardinality (if high, one hot encoding might not be the best approach).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the series.map() function is to replace the values in the provided dictionary, and change other values to `NaN`. If you want to run the same line of code multiple times, then all values need to be accounted for. You can either use a defaultdict, which allows a default value to be set, or just include the result of the first run as inputs in case you run it a second time. 
Change

```
dfcat = dataset['label']=dataset.label.map({'ham':1,'spam':0})
```

to

```
dfcat = dataset['label']=dataset.label.map({'ham':1,'spam':0,1:1,0:0})
```